# How to enable VNC options through Remote Management

Tags: terminal, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I'm looking for a way to script the Remote Management section in Sharing System Preferences. What I'm trying accomplish is to script the Computers Settings button and everything inside it. So far I have:

```
alias kickstart="/System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart"
sudo kickstart -activate -configure -allowAccessFor -specifiedUsers -restart -agent
sudo kickstart -activate -configure -users hcpadmin -access -on -privs -all -restart -agent
sudo kickstart -clientopts -setreqperm -reqperm yes
sudo kickstart -clientopts -setvnclegacy -vnclegacy yes
sudo kickstart -clientopts -setvncpw -vncpw *******
sudo kickstart -configure -computerinfo -set1 -1 User\ Name
sudo kickstart -configure -computerinfo -set2 -2 Location\ and\ Cube\ #
sudo kickstart -configure -computerinfo -set3 -3 Desktop\ Asset Tag\ #
sudo kickstart -configure -computerinfo -set4 -4 Display\ Asset\ Tag\ #
```

But I can't seem to get is the "Anyone may request..." checked and the VNC with password checked and working. Has anyone ever got this working?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help. I got Kickstart: command not found when I tried to run it. Am I missing something?

Comment: OOPS! Okay, so I removed all the sudos from the beginning of each line. It's getting better! I'm getting an error with the # at the end of the last 3 lines. Am I supposed to enter that differently when trying to script this?